# Gitlab CI Valgrind Leak Check setup?

Tags: c, continuous-integration, gitlab, valgrind

is there a way to setup a Valgrind check like 
`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes ./prakt1`
inside Gitlab CI?

If so, how would one do it? Is it free to run those kind of tests, or do i have to pay for it?
I have a Gitlab Account from my University.

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your account on the public gitlab.com or on your University's own GitLab?  Public gitlab.com provides GitLab CI runners free of charge courtesy of Digital Ocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/press/releases/gitlab-partnership-with-digitalocean/).  (Runners run your CI jobs.)

You can run any command you want inside GitLab CI using the `script` attribute in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

Comment: Thanks! It's on the university's own Gitlab. I'll have a look at the documentation.